# sql How to get sum of a distinct values according to set of distincted condition query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get two columns with group1 having distinct values where c3= yes and group2 where it has sum(c2) according to group1 .

```
c1   |   c2   | c3
--------------|-----
A    |   2    |yes
B    |   1    |yes
A    |   2    |yes
B    |   1    |yes
C    |   2    |no
C    |   1    |no




result :


group1 | group2
---------------
A      | 4
B      | 2
```

I am trying this query but not working

```
SELECT SUM(c2) WHERE DISTINCT c1 in('A','B') and c3='yes' as 'group2' from table,
    SELECT DISTINCT c1 in('A','B') as 'group1' from table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT c1 as group1, SUM(c2) as group2 FROM table 
WHERE c3="yes"
GROUP BY c1
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark answer as accepted, and do it whenever you get the answer you were looking for on SO @phpnet